# NSString's stringWithContentsOfURL uses browser cookies?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cookies, nsstring

I'm working on an objective-c project that downloads webpages from a community website and parses the results. The download code looks like this:

```
NSError* error = nil;
    NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    if(text) {
        return text;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
        return nil;
    }
```

The odd thing is that when I download from the site I see resulting content that I would only see if logged into the site (which, in my browser, I am).

Does that method (NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error) use browser cookies when executing the request? If so, is it Safari specifically that it's integrated with? The default browser? I can't seem to find documentation describing the behavior that I'm seeing. I'm ok with the behavior (in fact, it's preferable), but I only want to depend on it if I fully understand what's going on.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you verify with a network logging tool (e.g. wireshark) that it uses a cookie of your browser?

Comment: I have confirmed using Wireshark that cookies are indeed being sent along with a GET request. Verified that the request was sent with the user agent set to my process name and performed the capture with all browsers terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are automatically handled and stored in an app's `NSHTTPCookieStorage` shared instance. Call the `cookies` method and check to see if your cookie is there. If it is, then that confirms your suspicion.

EDIT: I highly suspect you are using a `UIWebView` in your app and logging in from there. In that case, then yes, cookies are stored in your app's `NSHTTPCookieStorage` shared instance and will be used with further URL requests.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any embedded web content (save for things I download and then turn into images, etc. myself). No UIWebView is involved and the only place any HTTP requests are being made is using the init method originally mentioned. That said, it looks like you're right about it being NSHTTPCookieStorage. The reference mentions that the cookies are shared across process boundaries and kept in sync, and it looks like all of the foundation URL/HTTP code makes use of them. Now that I understand that this is understood behavior I can count on I will make use of it :)

Comment: It sounds to me like the questioner is writing a Mac app. (For one thing, there is no “default browser” choice on iOS; the default browser on iOS is, currently, always Safari.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to be true for me. I have a switch in my app if the user wishes to remember his session, which in effect saves the current session cookie. But stringWithContentsOfURL only works when the user logs in, which creates and saves a new session cookie. If the user logs in because the switch was on to remember the session, stringWithContentURL gives me back a "Unauthorized API Access". I even checked to see if my old cookie was in CookieStorage, and it was.